# Error: 1631 Connection Failed google calendar api filemkaer

Tags: google-calendar-api, filemaker

when i am trying to create an event using google api i have an error: 1631 connection failed.

trying to access using "Insert from URL"
where $responseAPI is a variable to store the response

URL:
"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" & $calendarId & "/events? access_token" & $accessToken
cURL:
"-x POST -H \"Content-type: application/json\" --data & Quote($data)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You need to provide more context and information.